# Cannot add class or attribute to elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add individual id's to each of my div tags that has the class "chapter". By putting in an alert box, I have checked that it does indeed iterate over 16 elements which is what is expected since this is the number of div elements with the class "chapter". I tried both adding another class (via addClass) and adding an id to the elements as below. But it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chapter").each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'chapter' + index + 1);
    });
});
```

html:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Programming examples for 70-480</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="70-480.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Programming examples for 70-480</h1>
        <h4>Training Guide Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3</h4>
        <ul>
            <div class="chapter"><li>Chapter 1: Getting started with Visual Studio 2012 and Blend for Visual Studio 2012</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lesson 1: Visual Studio 2012</li>
                    <li>Lesson 2: Blend for Visual Studio 2012</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="chapter"><li>Chapter 2: Getting started with HTML5</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lesson 1: Introducing HTML5</li>
                    <li>Lesson 2: Embedding content</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            ...
```

Comment: should be `$(this).attr('id', 'chapter' + (index + 1));` to force the numeric addition to be done properly - otherwise it's all string concatenation

Comment: The issue here is because your HTML is invalid. the `div` elements are not allowed to be direct descendants or `ul` elements and are being removed/moved elsewhere in the DOM. You should make the `.chapter` elements in to `li`, then your code will work fine.

Comment: Also that markup is not valid. The only proper children for `<ul>` elements are `<li>` elements, not `<div>`

Comment: @Pointy true about the addition not being added properly, but it would still return a string as the id

Comment: @Huangism true; the OP didn't really say what "it doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is because your HTML is invalid. the `div` elements are not allowed to be direct descendants or `ul` elements and are being removed/moved elsewhere in the DOM. You should add the `chapter` class to the top level `li`, then your code will work fine.

```
<ul>
    <li class="chapter">
        Chapter 1: Getting started with Visual Studio 2012 and Blend for Visual Studio 2012
        <ul>
            <li>Lesson 1: Visual Studio 2012</li>
            <li>Lesson 2: Blend for Visual Studio 2012</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="chapter">
        Chapter 2: Getting started with HTML5
        <ul>
            <li>Lesson 1: Introducing HTML5</li>
            <li>Lesson 2: Embedding content</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also, as @Pointy suggested you need to wrap the `index + 1` logic in brackets to prevent it being interpreted as string concatenation:

```
$(".chapter").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'chapter' + (index + 1));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/793uakq8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo :

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/qzvfswz8/63/)

Here is the JS:

```
$(".chapter").each(function(index) {
var index = index+1;
$(this).attr('id', 'chapter' + index);
});
```